# Maximum Bookings and Bernoulli Distribution

Tags: probability

> An air flight can carry $m$ passengers. A passenger with a reserved seat arrives for the flight with probability $p$. Assume that the passengers behave independently. 
>   What is the maximum number of seats the airline should reserve for the probability that more passengers arrive than the flight can seat to be less than $(1-q)$?

My working: I know the way to calculate the minimum number of bookings. For maximum bookings $n$, should I equate the expectation np = m? But then what is the use of the probability $(1-q)$?
Please help.

Comment: If $X$ is the number of passenger who arrives, $X\sim B(n,p)$. You are looking to solve $P(X>m)\le 1-q \implies P(X\le m) \ge q$.

Comment: Makes sense. But then the left hand-side is a tedious Binomial Expression. Can that be solved without use of programming?